# Defined integrals-Aplications

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, radicals

1)

Calculate the area of the function bordered by function graph
$f : (0, ∞) → R$, $f (x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{x+1}$

and  axe Ox, lines $x=1$ and $ x =4 $

//On this I get stuck and sqrt(x) under x+1 (but idk if I make it right))

2)$f : [0, 3] → R, f (x) =3x-x^2$

Get $ m ∈ R$ such that the ecuation line $y = mx$ to 
to separate  function subgraph in $2 $multitudes of equal areas

//Here I don't understand what I should do

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: 1)Solved with variable change you change sqrt(x) after some calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) I get it as if you should find the slope (that is find $m$) of the straight line so that the two domains (together with the $x$-axis) painted in different colors in the animation below have the same area.

[image: animation]

The total area between $y=3x-x^2$ and the $x$-axis is given by
$$
\int_0^3 3x-x^2\,dx.
$$
The area under the blue graph but above the orange line is given by... well, I leave it for you to figure that out. I think you can find that out. If not, ask in a comment and I'll give you some hint.

Comment: First of all  thanks a lot for support,I get the area that is 9/2 and I have the answer at the end of exercise of the method of getting the M but I still don't see the solution.The area that you said is should be the half of the entire area,but you wanted me to say that is some tangent or some function .Btw how you did that  graph?

Comment: Thanks. I guess your problem is solved since you marked the answer? If not, tell me and I'll update with more info. The graph was made with the software Mathematica.

Comment: I said that I have the answer (the last calculations to get the results ) but I don't know how to get there.Btw how you solve integral of x/(e^x  +1) ?

Comment: Edit2: So the final result (9/2) is (X^3)/2 and to get m it replaced x with x-m that is strange to replace at the argument of the base and to keep the exponent